# pandas assign different values to a column depends on the values in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `df`,

```
days
NaN
70
29
```

I like to do

```
df['short_days'] = np.where(df.days < 30, 'Yes', 'No')
```

but when it is `NaN`, `df.short_days = 'Not Applicable'`, so the result will look like,

```
days    short_days
NaN     Not Applicable
70      No
29      Yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to fill nan values with anything you want

```
import numpy as np

df['short_days'] = np.where(df.days < 30, 'Yes', 'No')
df['short_days'].fillna('Not Applicable',inplace=True)
```

```
days    short_days
NaN     Not Applicable
70      No
29      Yes
```

Comment: is `NaN` not recognized as float?

Comment: you can do `float('nan')` and it would return nan or using `math.isnan('nan')`so kind of it is recognized as float but i am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

More elegant to use `np.select` here where you can define a `default` value:

```
df['short_days'] = np.select([df.days<30, df.days>=30], 
                             ['Yes', 'No'], 
                             default='Not Applicable')
```

**Output**

```
   days      short_days
0   NaN  Not Applicable
1  70.0              No
2  29.0             Yes
```